# Android Optionsmenu does not change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

So my problem is, is that I have a fragment. This fragment is used for creating new objects and editing existing objects. 
When I create a new objects, I want to have a save button. And when I edit an object I also want a delete button.
I have two menu layout files. Which are
R.menu.element_actionbar_edit

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/action_delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
    android:title="@string/delete"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_done"
    android:title="@string/save"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

R.menu.element_actionbar_add

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_done"
    android:title="@string/save"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Whenever the fragment with all the actions is called, it only onCreateOptionsMenu.

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.element_actionbar_add, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Eventhough I call the R.menu.add layout it still adds two items to the actionbar, before it actually inflates the menu already contains two items.
This fragment is the only place where I actually use a menu right now.
 First I had added an if statement in the options create, to check if there was passed an existing object to edit, but in this case it did show the correct layout, but when nothing is passed I should get only the save button?
Why does it show the wrong layout, without even specifying it anywhere else?

EDIT:
So it worked!

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(currentObject==null) {
        Global.ACTIVITY.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.element_actionbar_add, menu);
    }else{
        Global.ACTIVITY.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.element_actionbar_edit,menu);
    }
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

At first setting the menu using the onPrepare didn't work either. I had to delete the app from my phone completely, and reinstall it to make it work.

Comment: See if cleaning the project (from Studio: Build -> Clean Project) helps. As regarding which menu to show depending of new/edit object... inflate different menu files depending of your object, eg.: `if(object==null){inflater.inflate(R.menu.element_actionbar_add, menu); else {inflater.inflate(R.menu.element_actionbar_edit, menu);}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If you want your menus to change dynamically you should not
use onCreateOptionMenu instead use onPrepareOptionMenus

    @Override
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    if(save){

    menu.add(0, ADD, 0, "Save");
    }
  else{
      // add rest
     }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

this method is called each time you click your menu button and menu.clear() is must since each time you add a menu.
Kindly share your results after implementing.